# Is the validation_mean_error of a trained neural network a sufficient indicator to choose a specific network over others?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, model-evaluation

I have trained a few different neural networks for a regression problem and now I am trying to evaluate which one is the best.

Is it sufficient to look at the mean validation error of the NN to say that Network A is better than Network B and should therefore be chosen, or do I have to look at other metrics as well to be able to make such a decision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The choice of your metric really depends on your problem and what you are trying to achieve. I would say that it is a good criteria to choose which NN to use. But it is always good to use more than one metric if possible.

Furthermore, you might have a trade off between complexity and performance. So if your complexity and training time are much higher but the MSE is only slightly better, maybe it is not the best network for your problem.

You can also experiment with different loss functions and see how it affects your results.